# How is it possible that two Android phones with different physical screen sizes are detected as equal by the system?

Tags: android, screen, android-screen-support

I have a Lenovo A1000 and a Samsung Galaxy Duos. You can see them in the attached pictures.

I am trying to make different values folders for each of them so I can fix some dimensions but they both just same to go under one folder. When I downloaded the What's my size app it detected them as they have similar screens? How is that even possible and is there any way I can detect the different screen sizes?

I tried with values-sw320dp-hdpi to catch the Lenovo, but the Samsung fell into it too. Any other ways?

[image]

Comment: please go through this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Please, I did 4 times. How would you detect the difference?